# ul customization to include a Quantity

Tags: css, list, html-lists, unordered

So, I'm stuck trying to get `CSS` to insert a quantity between the bullet and the ul item description. Thanks for your help.

```
* abc 
* efg
* hijklmnop
```

to

```
* 125 abc 
* 5   efg
* 20  hijklmnop
```

Thank you in advance for your help.
[image]

Comment: Can you post your css/html and any javascript so to better assist you.

Comment: I wasn't clear. I simply wanted to create a 3 column format
Bullet Qty Description. Looking for a cool way to modify the <ul> class. Thanks.

Comment: Simply looking to insert a quantity between the bullet and the description while allowing the description to wrap around and stay in the description column.
Obviously I could just add the Qty to the <li></li> but then qty and description will be in the same column. Thanks.

Comment: So you're looking to have three columns, and unlimited rows? There's this thing called a table... :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to use CSS to add content, but you could do something like [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/RLPME/2/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="add_125">abc</li>
    <li class="add_5">efg</li>
    <li class="add_20">hijklmnop</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.add_125:before {
    content:'125 ';
}
.add_5:before {
    content:'5 ';
}
.add_20:before {
    content:'20 ';
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to present [Bullet] [qty] [description] in a better way using the <ul> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't use CSS to insert random numbers between a list item and its dot. The best you could do would be to wrap the number in a div and give it a width so the text will line up together.

Something like:

```
<li><div style="width:50px">125</div> Contrary to popular... </li>
```

Comment: The problem with the above is that the quantity stays inline with the bullet and pushes the description to a new line.

[Bullet] [qty] [description]